# Unable to include C++ headers in Code::Blocks SDL program?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to execute a bare bones SDL program. I followed the instructions in tutorial [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php). 
Program builds and executes as expected with C headers(stdlib.h for printf()). But it throws me an error when i try to use iostream(for cout). Build message says "fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory".

**How to use C++ features with SDL2?** It wont even allow me to use bool or classes. Program executes just fine when i use C functions and data types.

I have *Code::Blocks 16.01* and *SDL 2.05*.

I am new to SDL and all these stuff , please dont be rude. I know question might sound silly to you guys. I searched for solution here and didn't found any relevant answer related to this. If SDL installation is incorrect, please point the correct steps. I would be grateful if someone helps me to figure this out! Thanks.

Sorry for poor English, please comment if question sounds unclear.

P.S: This code executes for me because i commented out C++ part.

```
#include<SDL.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//#include<iostream>
//using namespace std;

const int screen_width=250;
const int screen_height=500;

int main(int argc,char* args[])
{
SDL_Window *window=NULL;
//SDL_Window is new data type. Always initialize pointer to NULL.

SDL_Surface* screenSurface=NULL;
//SDL_Surface is new data type. Surface is just a 2d image

//cant call any SDL function without initializing it before..

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)<0)
{

}
//cout<<"SDL could not be initialized! Error:"<<SDL_GetError();

else
{
    //creating a window

    window=SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,screen_width,screen_height,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    //just a error check again. make it habit to check for error always!!
    if(window==NULL)
    {
    //cout<<"Sorry window could not be created!"<<SDL_GetError();
    }

    else
    {
        //get window surface. surface of window of type SDL_Window is returned to type of surface of SDL_Surface
        screenSurface=SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

        //fill the surface
        SDL_FillRect(screenSurface,NULL,SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF));

        //update the surface!, you always need to update surface !!

        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

        //wait for defined amount of time! time is in millisecs

        SDL_Delay(2000);

        //destroy window
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

        //quite SDl subsystems

        SDL_Quit();

    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you compile? (edit your question to show it) Can you compile an empty `main(){}` program with C++ headers, but without SDL headers?

Comment: Only error i get is "fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory". If i comment out iostream header, i don't get any errors.

Comment: About empty main function, it doesn't works if try to do it in a empty project like mentioned in above tutorial. If i select Console Application while creating project, everything works fine but then i cant include SDL libraries..

Comment: I think you are compiling a C program. The file must have *.cpp extension, not C extension. It wouldn't have anything to do with SDL.

Comment: yes, thanks>>!! you're right..very dumb mistake!! Thank you so much..! :)